# Save image using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Android development, and im making simple aplication that capture image then save. I can capture the image and show into imageview, but unfortunately i cannot save into gallery.

i tryed many ways but cannot save. this is original code to take and show.

// EDITED //

I add function to save file, but still not working

```
class TomarFotos : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var photoPath: String
    val REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tomar_fotos)
        val foto = findViewById<Button>(R.id.tomarfotos)
        foto.setOnClickListener{
            tomarFoto()
        }
    }
    fun tomarFoto()  {
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        if(intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null){

            var photoFile: File? = null
            try{
                photoFile = createImageFile()
            }catch (e: IOException){}
            if(photoFile != null){
                val photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    this,
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile
                )
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri)
                startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            }
       }
    }
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        val fotoTomada = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.fotopreview)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            fotoTomada.rotation = 90f
            fotoTomada.setImageURI(Uri.parse(photoPath))
        }
    }
    private fun createImageFile(): File? {
            val fileName = "foto"
            val storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
            val image = File.createTempFile(
                fileName,
                ".jpg",
                storageDir
            )
            photoPath = image.absolutePath
            return image

    }
}


i try developer.android.com already but didnt work
```

Comment: You are not capturing an image. What you get is only a thumbnail of a possible image. Change your code so the camera app writes the image file at a location you determine.

Comment: already change it, but still not working

Comment: Not workin? What does that mean? What happens instead?

Comment: it take the pic, and show it on ImageView, but dont save it

Comment: If the camera app did not save it you could not display it. So what happens? Be exact!

Comment: hmmm i cant find the image on the device where im testing the app, this can be other problem then? i take the picture on the app then i try to find it on "file" directory or in "gallery"

Comment: getExternalFilesDir() is a private directory for your app. This means that no other app can find it or has access. Also file managers have no access on Android 11+.

Comment: ohhh ok, so what i should use instead getExternalFilesDir() ?

Comment: Well which other .get##### functions do you know? Try them all.

Comment: Ok! I'm going that way

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    val fotoTomada = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.fotopreview)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val imageBitmap = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
        fotoTomada.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
        saveImage(imageBitmap)
    }
}
```

Call this function to save image to gallery

```
private fun saveImage(bitmap: Bitmap) {
    var outStream: FileOutputStream? = null
    // Write to SD Card
    try {
        val dir = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + File.separator + "AppName/")
        dir.mkdirs()
        val fileName = "IMG_${System.currentTimeMillis()}"
        val outFile = File(dir, fileName)
        outStream = FileOutputStream(outFile)
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream)
        outStream.flush()
        outStream.close()
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Image Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
        Log.d("TAG", "saveImage: ${e.message}")
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.d("TAG", "saveImage: ${e.message}")
    } 
}
```